# Error in onclick function

Tags: jquery, html

I added onclick event to below query, but it doesn't  work. I used ruby on rails . Help me out to get a solution. Thank you...

```
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
   $('#sub').append("<div class='col-md-12' '><img src='picture.jpg' class='subPic' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='sayhello()'></div>");
}
function sayhello(){
  alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: `function name()` and `onclick = name()`

Comment: your updated code is working.. what is the error you are encountering?

Comment: where you able to append the img? if not then maybe `result["prd_image"].length;` is the problem..

Comment: I changed it. but error is still the same . I coded this on ruby on rails . is it the problem?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Try to read in [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593650/working-with-javascript-in-a-view-in-ruby-on-rails).

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: sayhello is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onclick (VM23994 89:1) is appeared in browser console

Comment: i edited to function name to sayhello()

Comment: then define `function sayhello() { alert("hello"); }` maybe there's some typo on the naming.

Comment: nope i already defined it before i reply to the comment

Comment: this is odd if you say the truth and really there's no typo. I suspect there's some error on some line that prevent your below scripts working correctly (and your function ended up not being defined).

Comment: error is i defined that sayhello function inside of wrong function

Comment: I find this a bit strange " $('#sub').append("<div class='col-md-12' '>" to single quotes followed.. not sure if this will cause any issues.. I suspect it might

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs a name. I chose the name "callAlert" here.

```
for (var j = 0; j < result["prd_image"].length; j++){
   $('#sub').append("<div class='col-md-12' '><img src='picture.jpg' class='subPic' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='callAlert()'></div>");
}
function callAlert(){
  alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: Do you have any output on browser console?

Comment: Yeah " Uncaught ReferenceError: sayhello is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (VM23994 89:1)"

Comment: error is i defined that sayhello function inside of wrong function thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a name to the function, like `function sayhello()` and then call it like `onclick='sayhello()'`

```js
for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
  $('#sub').append("<div class='col-md-12' '><img src='picture.jpg' class='subPic' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='sayhello()' alt='awda'></div>");
}

function sayhello() {
  alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sub"></div>
```

Comment: these changes are worked in here. but i in my code errors are still the same. I'm working my project on ruby on rails .

Comment: VM23994 89:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: sayhello is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (VM23994 89:1) error is appeared in browser console

Comment: error is i defined that sayhello function inside of wrong function thanks for your cooperation